# Google reCaptcha validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have problem with Jquery validation nad google reCaptcha, I have HTML website with form and I included Jquery validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/, I had no problem with validating fields, but I would also like to validate google reCaptcha, if it is empty or not.

So only reqest that I need to add in my validaiton rule would be to check if recaptcha if empty or not. I tried same way as input fields but it didn't work, so i found this great toturial how to include validation - https://bubinga.co/combining-googles-recaptcha-and-jquery-validate/

But still doesn't work. Here is my code that is used but it doesn't work, it doesn't validate the recpatcha everythign else works fine. Without validation recpatcha works normally but i would like to include it in validation notw.

HTML code where div is inserted for recaptcha:

```
   <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcRxx8TAAAAACq0p7qA2H2519UNqtw5mtw-k_qB"></div>
```

Under JS rules i added:

```
 hiddenRecaptcha: {
                    required: function() {
                        if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Under JS messages:

```
 hiddenRecaptcha: "Your Captcha response was empty. Please try again."
```

It is kinda stupid problem but i don't know where the problem is, did i forgot to include something extra for this part to be validated ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you tell jQuery validate not to ignore hidden fields (as per the tutorial you've linked to)?